Grafana alerts are not separated on Slack
I use prometheus, alertmanager, grafana and loki for monitoring.
I want to distinguish my grafana alerts to critical and warning severity.
When only one of the alerts is configured: trash-watchdog-warning or trash-watchdog-critical it sends to Slack notifications with alerts filtered by the added condition to the expression for loki: num_of_failures <= 10 or num_of_failures > 10 with appropriate severity: *Severity:* Critical or *Severity:* Warning.
When two alerts are in the configuration I receive severity *Severity:* :question: {{ .CommonLabels.severity }} and all of the alerts are sent including > 10 and <= 10.
Serverity is sent based on the template:
      {{/* Severity of the alert */}}
      {{ define "__alert_severity" -}}
          {{- if eq .CommonLabels.severity "critical" -}}
          *Severity:* `Critical`
          {{- else if eq .CommonLabels.severity "warning" -}}
          *Severity:* `Warning`
          {{- else if eq .CommonLabels.severity "info" -}}
          *Severity:* `Info`
          {{- else -}}
          *Severity:* :question: {{ .CommonLabels.severity }} 
          {{- end }}
      {{- end }}

My grafana alerting configuration:
  alerting:
    rules.yaml:
      apiVersion: 1
      editable: true
      groups:
        - orgId: 1
          name: trash-watchdog
          folder: trash-watchdog
          interval: 5m
          name: trash-watchdog-warning
          folder: trash-watchdog-warning
          interval: 2m
          rules:
            - uid: watchdog-errors-warning
              title: watchdog-errors-warning
              condition: B
              data:
                - refId: A
                  queryType: instant
                  relativeTimeRange:
                    from: 600
                    to: 0
                  datasourceUid: loki
                  model:
                    datasource:
                      type: loki
                      uid: loki
                    editorMode: code
                    expr: 'sum by (parser_name, parser_hash, parser_id, error_msg, url, laravel_dashboard_url, num_of_failures) (count_over_time({pod=~"pod-name.*"} |= `failed with errors` | json | line_format "{{`{{.msg}}`}}" | __error__=`` | pattern `some pattern` | label_format url="https://some-url.com/" | num_of_failures <= 10 [$__range]) > 0)'
                    intervalMs: 1100
                    maxDataPoints: 43200
                    queryType: instant
                    refId: A
                - refId: B
                  relativeTimeRange:
                    from: 600
                    to: 0
                  datasourceUid: __expr__
                  model:
                    conditions:
                      - evaluator:
                          params:
                            - 0
                            - 0
                          type: gt
                        operator:
                          type: and
                        query:
                          params: []
                        reducer:
                          params: []
                          type: avg
                        type: query
                    datasource:
                      name: Expression
                      type: __expr__
                      uid: __expr__
                    expression: A
                    hide: false
                    intervalMs: 1100
                    maxDataPoints: 43200
                    refId: B
                    type: threshold
              noDataState: OK
              execErrState: Error
              for: 0s
              annotations:
                summary: "Summary"
                description: 'Parser {{`{{ $labels.parser_id }}`}} {{`{{ $labels.parser_name }}`}} {{`{{ $labels.parser_hash }}`}} failed with an error: "{{`{{ $labels.error_msg }}`}}", failures in a row: {{`{{ $labels.num_of_failures }}`}} - <{{`{{ $labels.url }}`}}|Open> - <https://some-url.com/grafana/d/e5216fef-ad5c-439f-8924-2a22e6ea0f67/some-dashboard?orgId=1&refresh=30s&from=now-24h&to=now&var-datasource=loki&var-parserId={{`{{ $labels.parser_id }}`}}|Open> - <https://some-url/grafana/d/bca48b7d-67e3-469e-8877-8cedbed3063f/watchdog-errors?orgId=1&refresh=30s&var-datasource=loki&from=now-24h&to=now&var-parserId={{`{{ $labels.parser_id }}`}}|Open>'
              labels:
                alertmanager_no_resolved: "true"
                severity: "warning"
              isPaused: false

        - orgId: 1
          name: trash-watchdog-critical
          folder: trash-watchdog-critical
          interval: 1m
          rules:
            - uid: watchdog-errors
              title: watchdog-errors
            - uid: watchdog-errors-critical
              title: watchdog-errors-critical
              condition: B
              data:
                - refId: A
                  queryType: instant
                  relativeTimeRange:
                    from: 600
                    to: 0
                  datasourceUid: loki
                  model:
                    datasource:
                      type: loki
                      uid: loki
                    editorMode: code
                    expr: 'sum by (parser_name, parser_hash, parser_id, error_msg, url, num_of_failures) (count_over_time({pod=~"pod-name.*"} |= `failed with errors` | json | line_format "{{`{{.msg}}`}}" | __error__=`` | pattern `some-pattern` | label_format url="https://some-url.com/{{`{{.parser_id}}`}}/main-settings" [$__range]) > 0)'
                    expr: 'sum by (parser_name, parser_hash, parser_id, error_msg, url, laravel_dashboard_url, num_of_failures) (count_over_time({pod=~"pod-name.*"} |= `failed with errors` | json | line_format "{{`{{.msg}}`}}" | __error__=`` | pattern `some-pattern` | label_format url="https://some-url" | num_of_failures > 10 [$__range]) > 0)'
                    intervalMs: 1000
                    maxDataPoints: 43200
                    queryType: instant
                    refId: A
                - refId: B
                  relativeTimeRange:
                    from: 600
                    to: 0
                  datasourceUid: __expr__
                  model:
                    conditions:
                      - evaluator:
                          params:
                            - 0
                            - 0
                          type: gt
                        operator:
                          type: and
                        query:
                          params: []
                        reducer:
                          params: []
                          type: avg
                        type: query
                    datasource:
                      name: Expression
                      type: __expr__
                      uid: __expr__
                    expression: A
                    hide: false
                    intervalMs: 1000
                    maxDataPoints: 43200
                    refId: B
                    type: threshold
              noDataState: OK
              execErrState: Error
              for: 0s
              annotations:
                summary: "Summary"
                description: 'Parser {{`{{ $labels.parser_id }}`}} {{`{{ $labels.parser_name }}`}} {{`{{ $labels.parser_hash }}`}} failed with an error: "{{`{{ $labels.error_msg }}`}}", failures in a row: {{`{{ $labels.num_of_failures }}`}} - <{{`{{ $labels.url }}`}}|Open> - <https://some-url.com/grafana/d/e5216fef-ad5c-439f-8924-2a22e6ea0f67/some-dashboard?orgId=1&refresh=30s&from=now-24h&to=now&var-datasource=loki&var-parserId={{`{{ $labels.parser_id }}`}}|Open> - <https://some-url/grafana/d/bca48b7d-67e3-469e-8877-8cedbed3063f/watchdog-errors?orgId=1&refresh=30s&var-datasource=loki&from=now-24h&to=now&var-parserId={{`{{ $labels.parser_id }}`}}|Open>'
              labels:
                alertmanager_no_resolved: "true"
                severity: "critical"
              isPaused: false

I'm looking for a reason of the behavior of incoming all of the alerts with wrong severity when two alerts are configured with different expression and different label.

IIUC, Alert grouping is the culprit here.
